# How would you solve this integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to solve this integral $$\int_1^{2}\int_\frac{1}{x}^{x^2}(y^2-x) dydx$$ However I don't get the right answer. I'm not showing what I have tried because I just want guidance on how to integrate the $dy$ part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to think about this is just to think of this problem in parts:

> (1)  $\int_1^{2}\underbrace{\int_\frac{1}{x}^{x^2}(y^2-x) dy}_{\text{you treat x like a constant and y like a variable here for now}}dx$.
>
> (2) So then you get $\int_1^{2}\underbrace{((\frac{y^3}{3}-xy)]_{\frac{1}{x}}^{x^2}}_{\text{you then do your definite integral part just replacing these values for y}}dx$.
>
> (3) $\int_1^{2}[\frac{(x^2)^3}{3}-x(x^2)]-[\frac{(\frac{1}{x})^3}{3}-x(\frac{1}{x})]dx$

Then, you got it from there.

Comment: Thanks for your help with the integration. That helped.

Comment: Glad it helped!!